# Как сменить кодировку в php 5.6.0RC4 на отличную от UTF-8?

Tags: кодировка, json_encode, php

Подскажите, как сменить кодировку в php 5.6.0RC4 на отличную от UTF-8. В php.ini менял default_charset на windows-1251, результата ноль. Можно было бы обойтись установкой заголовка, но есть и другая проблема. Распаковываю json (windows-1251) в массив, запаковываю json_encode() по частям в строку. Там, где должен получаться json с русскими символами, возвращается пустая строка. Чем лечить? Достаточно, если json начнет работать нормально.

В принципе, как решение я могу собирать его в строку руками, написав рекурсивную функцию. Но php это тот язык, где все написано, и хотелось бы, чтобы он таким и оставался.

Comment: > Чем лечить?

Переводом с помощью iconv (не забудьте про обработку несуществующих в cp1251 символов, рано или поздно всё равно придёт некорретный ввод).

> Подскажите, как сменить кодировку в php 5.6.0RC4 на отличную от UTF-8.

Честно говоря, весь мир мигрирует на utf-8 по причине его явных преимуществ. Но интернет мне нашептал, что передача `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` в качестве параметра `json_encode()` может помочь.

Answer (score 2):

```
json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```